# Extracting data from large JSON file using php: How can I implement listener interface in my code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working with large heavily nested JSON file, and want to use streaming parser by implementing a Listener interface found on [jsonstreamingparser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser). When I ran by php code, I receiced this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'InMemoryListener' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs. I think the error is on line that contains "$listener = new InMemoryListener();". I am new to using stream parser for JSON in PHP. I know what listener interface does is similar to what XMLPARSER does, and some kind of PHP listener interface has been created by some gurus, but I do not know how to implement it in my code. I put the supposed listener interface file named "InMemoryListener" in the same folder as my php code, but I still got error. Can anyone explain how I can implement  the Listener interface in my code? 
Below is my code:

```
 $stream = fopen('myJSONfile.json', 'r');
 $listener = new InMemoryListener();
 try {
   $parser = new \JsonStreamingParser\Parser($stream, $listener);
   $parser->parse();
   fclose($stream);
 } catch (Exception $e) {
   fclose($stream);
   throw $e;
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you imported source code from dependency manager like composer? did you included '/vendor/autoload.php' ?

Comment: I have added (1) require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; to the top of my code, (2) included $listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\InMemoryListener();, (3) also downloaded [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), but still I received this error: "Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php on line 2". Line 2 on the code has require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: I can see from here there is no vendor folder in your directory

Comment: Hi Shashi. I have downloaded all the required software successfully using composer require blablabla/blablabla. However, I got this error" Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'salsify\vendor\salsify\json' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php on line 6. Line 6 is $listener = new salsify\vendor\salsify\json-streaming-parser\src\Listener\In‌​MemoryListener();, which contains file path to the file named "InMemoryListener". I think I am still getting some things wrong but do not know. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Shashi, Thanks. I have fixed the error now. The problem was (1) I did not properly point to the location of autoload.php, (2) and the location of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install something with composer you need to ensure that composer's autoloader is included in your script execution. Add this to the top of your file:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Next, by the looks of the module you'll need to add a namespace to `InMemoryListener` as well:

```
$listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\InMemoryListener();
```

Comment: Hi Robbie, many thanks. I have added (1) `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of my code, (2) included `$listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\InMemoryListener();`, (3) also downloaded  [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/), but still I received this error: "Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php on line 2". Line 2 on the code has `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`. I know it is simple, perhaps because I am new. I ll be glad for your help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll also need to use composer to install the package you want to use. See their readme, it will have an example like `composer require abc/xyz`

Comment: Hi Robbie, I have downloaded all the required software successfully using `composer require blablabla/blablabla`. However, I got this error" `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'salsify\vendor\salsify\json' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\JSON0917.php on line 6`. Line 6 is `$listener = new salsify\vendor\salsify\json-streaming-parser\src\Listener\InMemoryListener();`, which contains file path to the file named "InMemoryListener". I think I am still getting some things wrong but do not know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Robbie, Thanks. I have fixed the error now. The problem was (1) I did not properly point to the location of autoload.php, (2) and the location of the class.